# Prove inequality of natural x, y, z

Tags: integral-inequality

Prove that, for every x , y, z of the natural inequality is true:

$x\ $ $+$ $y\ $ $+$ $z\ $ $\ge$ $3$  $and$ $x$*$y$*$z$ $=$ $1$

I tried to divide by 3, but does not go :(

Comment: I'm not sure I understand this correctly. you want to proove that vor every x,y,z ($\in\mathbb{R}$?) for which $x*y*z=1$  is true $x+y+z \geq 3$?

Comment: Yes, that's true :)

Comment: whats about (-1,-1,1) ?  x*y*z = 1 but x+y+z = -1

Comment: or do you want only positive real numbers

Comment: Yes, only positive :) My oversight :(

Answer (score 2):

HINT: we have $\frac{x+y+z}{3}\geq \sqrt[3]{xyz}=1$ by AM-GM

Comment: Where does the root level 3?

Comment: if you mean what it is, it is the revert function to f(x) = x^3

Comment: Ok, I know now :)

Comment: can you use the AM-GM?

Comment: No :( I can't :(

Comment: yes AM-GM works for numbers $a\geq 0,b\geq 0,c\geq 0$

Comment: What's next? This is end of prove?

Comment: yes this is the end of the proof

Comment: I ment: are you allowed to use the AM-GM.....

Comment: if it is not allowed he must remark ist

Comment: Yes, you can use this :) Sorry

Comment: I solve this ;) thanks